# LED strip flickering at low brightness, using ESP8266, IRF510 MOSFETs and 12V power

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, led-strip

I have a very simple circuit, where the ESP8266 controls a non-addressable 12V RGBW led strip.

I works properly at normal and high brightness, but when I set the brightness to low, the LED strip flickers. It's not a constant flickering, it's a random one.

Sometimes the light stays still for like 5 seconds, and all a sudden flickers a little, and then it goes back to normal.

I am using IRF510 MOSFETs for each channel, a Wemos D1, a 12V 2A switching power supply and a buck converter (LM2596) to supply the 3.3V for the Wemos D1 from the same 12V power supply.

The software part is taken care through Esphome, and then added to Home Assistant.

The connection cables are short and the LED strip is only 6 feet (2 meters) long.

I tried to add 4 capacitors to each of the RGBW that go to the LED strip, but it didn't do anything.

What can I do to prevent the flickering during low brightness?

This is the wiring diagram:

[image: wiring]

This is the board:

Front:

[image]

Back:

[image]

Comment: The flickering is likely caused from a low PWM frequency.  Try increasing it; look through the documentation and code.

Comment: The 7805 isn't a transistor, it's a 5V regulator.  It seems like that is the wrong part for the job.  Post a link to the datasheet if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry! It was a typo, I am using TIP102. I will edit the question. Thanks !

Comment: Edit the title as well (7805 is listed there too)

Comment: 1.  That's a wiring diagram, not a circuit schematic diagram. 2. You say you are using a TIP102 but the drawing shows FETs.  The TIP102 is an NPN BJT, not a FET.  3. Fritzing can produce schematic diagrams.  Schematic diagrams are of more use when discussing circuit function than wiring diagrams.  4. Assuming your circuit is correct (it does light up and you can control the brightness to some extent,) the most likely cause is a low PWM frequency.  Post your code.

Comment: BJT controls by current, base resistor is must.

Comment: Thanks @JRE for all the clarifications! I am new to all of this. I changed to IRF510 and they work better, but there is still a slight flickering when they are set to a very low brightness. I am not using any code, just the ESPHOME light component and Home Assistant to control them.